# How to verify which users are editing a document at the moment?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using Google Drive's API to store/edit/preview documents. Right now I need to find out which users are editing the document at the moment.

I've read the files API and some other references at Google's documentation page to no avail.

[Files API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files)

Does anyone know how to check for that information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response data of every Drive API (specially those in Files And Changes) doesn't contain anything that will exactly match your requirement. But I guess you might wanna check on how you can utilize [watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/watch) endpoint which is the closest thing I can suggest.

Comment: I thought so when I didn't find anything... unfortunately... Thanks.